# What does ままにした mean?

Tags: syntax

What does it mean in the sentence below?

> 彼は私を午前中ずっと待たせた**ままにした**。

Comment: Potential overlap with [Meaning of そのままにする] http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/13863/16235

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 「彼{かれ}は私{わたし}を午前中{ごぜんちゅう}ずっと待{ま}たせた**ままにした**。」

「ままにする」 means "to leave", "to keep", etc.

> "He left me waiting all morning."

For those keen on pronunciation, 「まま」 and 「ママ」 are pronounced differently.

「[まま]{LH}」

「[ママ]{HL}」